# download files from google drive is very dangerous?! All files got exec permission?

Tags: linux, permissions, zip

I just found out. If you download several files (any file, text, image, binary) as zip from google drive. Then unpack it with Ark locally. All the files in that folder will automatically get exec permission ... This is very dangerous.

Any idea what is wrong here? I try to compress exactly same files into zip and unpack with Ark. The behaviour is normal. I try to unzip the downloaded zip file in terminal with `unzip xx.zip -d xx`. It also behave normally.

Answer (score 0):

The files get the generic set of permissions becuase ZIP does not hold file permissions in the archive.